# Unrecognized token AND

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, token

I am having problems in the next query:

This is my array of data

```
 String[] columns = new String[]
{ KEY_ROWELEMENTID, KEY_STUDYID,  KEY_ELEMENTCODE, KEY_ELEMENTNAME};
```

I create a cursor to this array where:
The column KEY_ELEMENTCODE is equal to a varable result 
AND 
KEY_STUDYID is equal to a varable result AND

```
 Cursor c = 
ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLEELEMENTS, columns,  KEY_ELEMENTCODE + "=" + elementRequest 
 + "AND" + KEY_STUDYID + 
"=" + idStudy, null, null, null, null);
```

What is the problem? I have debug and all variables has the correct values

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there should be space as " AND ",
One more thing, if you are comparing for Integer values then use this line,

```
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLEELEMENTS, columns,  
        KEY_ELEMENTCODE + "=" + elementRequest
                + " AND " + KEY_STUDYID +
                "=" + idStudy, null, null, null, null);
```

and if you are comparing string values then you should use single inverted comma as,

```
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLEELEMENTS, columns,
        KEY_ELEMENTCODE + "=" +"'"+elementRequest+"'"+
                + " AND " + KEY_STUDYID +
                "=" + "'"+idStudy+"'", null, null, null, null);
```

Let me know if it works for you...

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the output from

```
KEY_ELEMENTCODE + "=" + elementRequest + "AND" + KEY_STUDYID + "=" + idStudy
```

I guess that you just have to replace

```
"AND"
```

with

```
" AND "
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the spaces around AND.

- " AND " +

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add space before and after "AND" and write as " AND " , hope it will resolve your issue :)